# Извлечение пути картинки из первого попавшего изображения

Tags: php, wordpress, регулярные-выражения

Помогите побороть регулярку:
данные приходят в таком виде:

```
<img src="https://suite.loc:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/b6-1.png" alt="" /><h2>Содержание</h2><h2 data-wow-delay="0.01s">Вступление</h2>
Уникальность контента — один из самых важных факторов успешной оптимизации сайта. Дубликаты страниц представляют опасность для продвижения: они могут серьезно снизить позиции ресурса в поисковой выдаче и крайне отрицательно воспринимаются роботами-поисковиками вплоть до наложения санкций.Поэтому дубли нужно своевременно выявлять и удалять. Как научиться этому — в нашей инструкции для новичков.<img src="https://suite.loc:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/b6-2.png" alt="" /><h2 data-wow-delay="0.01s">Почему дубли опасны?</h2>
Дубли (копии) страниц — это блоки контента с одинаковым содержанием в пределах одного доменного имени.
Когда на сайте есть две или больше одинаковых страниц, поисковики не могут разобраться, какую из них нужно выдавать по соответствующему запросу.
Такая дилемма несет множество негативных последствий:<ul><li style="font-weight: 400;">Проблемы с индексацией сайта — если на каждую страницу будет по одному дубликату, то веб-ресурс увеличится в два раза. А если несколько дублей? Поисковики просто могут не проиндексировать все существующие страницы.</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Снижение позиций в поисковой выдаче — в органической выдаче может быть не основная страница, а ее дубликат. Или что еще хуже — ни одна из них.</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Снижение позиций ключевых слов, т.к. релевантная привязка будет постоянно меняться с одной страницы на другую.</li></ul>
<img src="https://suite.loc:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/b6-3.png" alt="" /><h2 data-wow-delay="0.01s">Виды дублей и почему они возникают</h2>
Копии страниц могут быть:<ul><li style="font-weight: 400;">полные — когда по двум или более адресам размещена одна и та же страница;</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">неполные — некоторая часть содержимого страницы частично присутствует на других страницах, но они являются только частичными копиями.</li></ul>
Причины возникновения <b><i>полных копий:</i></b><ul><li style="font-weight: 400;">Это могут быть идентичные страницы с www и без www, а также с html или https — появляются, если редирект настроен неправильно.</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Некорректная настройка страницы 404.</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Копии, созданные реферальной ссылкой, когда автоматическое перенаправление на URL без параметра «?ref=…» не происходит.</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Проблемы с иерархией URL.</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Случайное копирование контента разработчиком или контент-менеджером.</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Изменение структуры ресурса, когда страница получает новый адрес, а старый забывают удалить.</li></ul>
<b><i>Неполные дубликаты </i></b>найти не так просто, они не приводят к резкому снижению позиций в выдаче, а “отравляют” сайт постепенно. Их основные причины:<ul><li style="font-weight: 400;">Копии, созданные страницами пагинации, фильтров или сортировок. Например: когда пользователь выбирает определенный фильтр товаров, URL немного видоизменяется и Google будет индексировать его как отдельную страницу. Но по сути, часть контента на новой странице остается неизменной.</li><li style="font-weight: 400;">Отзывы, комментарии, обзоры — дубли появляютс...
```

Нужно получить путь из первого изображения `src=""` (всегда будет первым), результат должен быть:

```
https://suite.loc:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/b6-1.png
```

Пробовал:

```
1. echo preg_replace("/<img.+>(.+)\/>/", "$1", $p->post_content); // empty

2. echo preg_replace("/<img src=\"(.+)\"/", "$1", $p->post_content); // empty

3. echo preg_match("/<img.*?src=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\'].*?>/i", $p->post_content);
```

По 3 примеру, на сайте [онлайн проверка регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/) верно прописано, но возвращает 0.

Получаю пустое значение.

В регулярке не понимаю, возможно есть другой способ получить путь из src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('@src="([^"]+)"@', $p->post_content, $m);
    $src = array_pop($m);
    print_r($src);

    //output:
    //Array ( [0] => https://suite.loc:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/b6-1.png [1] => https://suite.loc:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/b6-2.png [2] => https://suite.loc:3000/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/b6-3.png )

    //первое изображение:
    echo '<img src="'.$src[0].'" />';
?>
```